# How can I write a PHP and MongoDB application using Apache SPARK?

Tags: php, mongodb, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have written a reporting application in PHP, which uses MongoDB as the database engine. Initially this application is working with a maximum of 1000 documents (or records) in the database collection (or table). Now I need to make this application ready for Big Data. For that I am considering to use Apache Spark as the big data framework so that I can process data in real time and generate analytics.

But I have heard that Apache Spark provides the Python and Scala options only. So my question is that how can I use it for PHP application which uses Mongodb as a database engine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't use your existing PHP codebase with Spark. You can however use existing database because MongoDB [has](https://www.mongodb.com/products/spark-connector) a special connector for Spark. If you'll run into some problems while rewriting your application use this site and we'll help you.

Comment: Are you saying that i'll have to rewrite my app in Python if I want to use Spark?

Comment: @JBel You can use Python, Java, Scala or R.  If your app is quite big, instead of rewriting all modules you can change some of them to connect (via external services for example) to newly written Spark parts. I would do it that way.

Comment: @JBel I don’t know but if you think that answer was helpful, you can upvote and accept it to mitigate that.

Comment: "If your app is quite big, instead of rewriting all modules you can change some of them to connect (via external services for example) to newly written Spark parts." - You mean I should write a webservice (like a REST API) right? If so, do you think it is good programming practice to write a web service for that reason, or is it like a hacky solution?

Comment: @JBel It depends on what is your end goal. If you want multiple data sources for final system then building a RESTful service is the best solution both in short term (speed of development) and long term. If you just want to scale it without building an overkill engine take your time and rewrite the whole thing.

Comment: Sorry something else came up and I could not tend to this for a few days. I have a follow-up question. I have already written the thing in PHP. It is working fine for a small dataset of around 500 records/rows. Now I've to make it ready for Big Data, so I am considering using Apache Spark. BUT IF I write REST API and consume it from Spark application, still all the heavy Big Data Processing will be done by PHP (since it is the PHP code which is connected to the database etc. ) rather than the Spark side of the app right?